# Unity fails to receive data from another app on certain port

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, udp

I have a C# game in unity which has to read from certain port:

```
Public const string ip = "127.0.0.1";
Public const int port = 5000;

IPEndPoint ipep =  new IPEndPoint(IPAdress.parse(ip),port); 
UdpClient uc = new UdpClient(ipep); 
byte[] res = uc.Recieve(ref ipep);
```

However I get an error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not respond

while data is being sent on that port from another running app all the time.

Comment: `IP` is not `ip`. Is this really your code? Also, so you have another app listening on UDP port 5000 and sending data if someone connects?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I typed it here because the code is on a disconnected machine

Comment: I think you are confused in terms of connecting and listening. Is your unity app supposed to listen on a certain port and some other app will connect to it and send data?

Comment: The other app is sending data to "127.0.0.1" port 5000 without waiting, all the time.

Comment: Yes, the other app is sending and unity is recieving.

Comment: Does the error occur rightaway or only after a certain timeout?

Comment: After a timeout

Comment: The code looks ok, i guess the error is on the other side.

Comment: This code on it's own looks ok. Without the server ( or "the other" ) side this question seems off-topic here.